# Firebase Event Guarantee: Event Order

Tags: firebase

I am just getting started with Firebase and had a question regarding the Firebase Event Guarantees listed at the following URL:
[Event Guarantees](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-event-guarantees).

One of the guarantees states that writes from a single client will always be written to the server and broadcast out to other users in-order.

Does this guarantee also imply that clients will receive events broadcast by a single client in the order that they were broadcast, or is it possible to receive events out of the order they were broadcast?

For example, if one client adds a node, then adds a child to that node, am I guaranteed that other clients will see those events in the same order?

Comment: The only guarantee is that the values will be eventually consistent. Thinking this through, it's the only reasonable answer. Any operation over the internet could be delayed indefinitely by any moving part in the process, thus producing out-of-order events received by the client, regardless of the order they reach the server.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only guarantee is that the values will be eventually consistent. Thinking this through, it's the only reasonable answer. Any operation over the internet could be delayed indefinitely by any moving part in the process, thus producing out-of-order events received by the client, regardless of the order they reach the server.

Thus, you are guaranteed that all the clients will see both of the added child nodes eventually, and that they will be consistent across all the clients (eventually).

If you want to guarantee the order of events, you are using a messaging queue--which is one adaptation of how you can use Firebase, but not the only one. This is easily achieved using the [push() method](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push), which creates chronologically ordered, unique ids.

You can also throw in a timestamp and utilize the [orderByChild](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/retrieving-data.html#section-queries) method to sort records.

Comment: Kato, when you say the data will be consistent _across all the clients (eventually)_, do you mean that if a client does receive an out of order event that the next event they receive will at least reflect the latest state? Or are you saying that of n events, the last event is guaranteed to be latest state?

Comment: See the events page linked by the OP. It's authoritative. Last event will be the latest state (nothing else makes sense here, btw).

Comment: Thanks for the response. I did read the events and other page sources, but I just wanted to be clear. To make my question clearer, if my client ends up with inconsistent data state (ie an event was never received), the only way for the state to become consistent again is for another event to occur?

Comment: Or does it mean that firebase server will retry to send the event and possibly have rolled up event changes?

Comment: I found a thread where it is discussed thoroughly. Seems you were part of it way back then :) Very insightful Google Groups thread https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/firebase-talk/aAbyCT3fQIc