# Does Firebase guarantee that data set using updateValues or setValue is available in the backend as one atomic unit?

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database

We have an application that uses base64 encoded content to transmit attachments to backend. Backend then moves the content to Storage after some manipulation. This way we can enjoy world class offline support and sync and at the same time use the much cheaper Storage to store the files in the end.

Initially we used `updateChildren` to set the content in one go. This works fairly well, but then users started to upload bigger and more files at the same time, resulting in silent freezing of the database in the end user devices.

We then changed the code to write the files one by one using `FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("/full/uri").setValue(base64stuff)`, and then using `updateChildren` to only set the metadata.

This allowed seemingly endless amount of files (provided that it is chopped to max 9 meg chunks), but now we're facing another problem.

Our backend uses Firebase listener to start working once new content is available. The trigger waits for the metadata and then starts to process the attachments. It seems that even though the client device writes the files *before* we set the metadata, the backend usually receives the metadata before the content from the files is available. This forced us to change backend code to stop processing and check later again if the attachment base64 data is available.

This works, but is not elegant and wastes cpu cycles and increases latencies.

**I haven't found anything in the docs wether Firebase guarantees anything about the order in which the data is received by the backend. It seems that everything written in one go (using `setValue` or `updateChildren`) is available in the backend as one atomic unit.**

**Is this correct? Can I depend on that as a fact that will not change in the future?**

The way I'm going to go about this (if the assumptions are correct above) is to write metadata first using `updateChildren` in the client like this

```
"/uri/of/metadata/uid/attachments/attachment_uid1" = "per attachment metadata"
"/uri/of/metadata/uid/attachments/attachment_uid2" = "per attachment metadata"
```

and then each base64 chunk using `updateChildren` with following payload:

```
"/uri/of/metadata/uid/uploaded_attachments/attachment_uid2" = true
"/uri/of/base64/content/attachment_uid" = "base64content"
```

I can't use setValue for any data to prevent accidental overwrite depending the order in which the writes will happen in the end.

This would allow me to listen to `/uri/of/base64/content` and try to start the handling of the metadata package every time a new attachment completes the load. The only thing needed to determine if all files have been already uploaded is to grab the metadata and see that all attachment uids found from /attachments/ are also present /uploaded_attachments/.

Comment: *firebaser here* Writes from a single Firebase Database client are delivered to the server in the same order as they are executed on the client. They are also broadcast out to any listening clients in the same order. Aside from that, it is hard to parse what is going on. Is there any way you can distill the problem to an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: Hi! Thanks for the input! I found this: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100656/firebase-event-guarantee-event-order

It is not a problem though now that I have re-architected our backend (which is one Firebase client) to cope with the eventually consistent nature of Firebase

To rephrase the question: "Does Firebase synchronize the order of events internally, so that there is no possibility, that events sent from one client are observed in another client in different order than written in (the first one)?" The answer to this is "There is no such guarantee." If I understood correctly?

Comment: No, that statement you just made is false. Writes from a single client are executed in order. There is no chance that another client will see the results of write B without seeing the results from write A (unless A was rejected by security rules).

Comment: Awesome! So the writes are guaranteed to be always in order. Then there's more to this story than meets the eye, but your previous comment answers my question fully. If you're kind enough to copy it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Done. If you still have problems, please post an [MCVE](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) so that we can see what's going on.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Writes from a single Firebase Database client are delivered to the server in the same order as they are executed on the client. They are also broadcast out to any listening clients in the same order.

There is no chance that another client will see the results of write B without seeing the results from write A (unless A was rejected by security rules)