# Firestore order of writes

Tags: firebase, google-cloud-functions, google-cloud-firestore

we've been using realtime database to save some data from mobile devices (ios, android + now web). I earlier asked if the order, in which other clients see the data, is guaranteed to be the same order in which client wrote those. (here [Does Firebase guarantee that data set using updateValues or setValue is available in the backend as one atomic unit?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44200589/does-firebase-guarantee-that-data-set-using-updatevalues-or-setvalue-is-availabl) , the title is a bit misleading, but the answer is there)

The answer was yes, and now we're migrating to Firestore and I'm wondering if the same applies to Firestore too?

So, If I write in client A documents 1, 2 and 3 is it guaranteed that Client N will observe the writes (given that there is a suitable listener) in the same order as client A wrote those?

Does this apply to Cloud Functions too? We're writing 3 pieces of data to separate documents and then we write fourth document as a way to trigger a function to do some processing. So is it guaranteed that the 3 documents written earlier will be available when the function is triggered?

Note that the 4 documents are NOT written in the same transaction or batch, but as separate document.create calls.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It would be catastrophically bad if the order of writes was not maintained within an individual client.  The client would not have a strong internal understanding of the state of the system after such a series of writes, and it would have to read every document back in order to validate the contents written.

So you can expect that the order would be maintained.  However, if you aren't using a transaction, there are no guarantees about the order of writes to document coming from multiple clients.

Comment: Thank you for clarifying this! (And thanks for the superb product :))

Comment: Btw, this is then badly outdated? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29100656
It discusses that the order of events is not guaranteed, just that the data will be eventually consistent?

Comment: Eventual consistency has to do with the way clients perceive each other's changes, not how a client perceives its own changes.  Use a transaction to prevent consistency problems.

Comment: The whole question was about how clients perceive each others writes. So I guess that the order in which client A observes the writes from client B is not guaranteed to be the same that client C observes?

Comment: Your question specifically calls out a single writer and multiple readers.  There should be no problems with that.  Use a transaction if there are multiple writers to the same location that need to be consistent.

Comment: Actually I think the single witer should be using a batch write if no transaction to ensure that all results hit at the same time.

Comment: @DougStevenson If a Collection is being inserted with new documents by multiple clients very close to each other in rapid succession, would the order of documents created be preserved? Does the size of the contents in the documents have a bearing on commits? Eg: A free text attribute in DocA created contains a very large text and was fired from the client first, while DocB with a smaller text fired second. Which would get committed first? Assuming that we are going to use transactions to perform these individual writes.