# The effect of entity group on transaction in google cloud firestore in datastore mode

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-datastore

I'm newbie to Google Cloud Firestore in Database mode, and I have a question about its transaction.

If there are two entities which belong to the same entity group, does an update of one entity on a transaction inhibits an update of the other entity on another transaction?

I show an example case below.

```
Entity A:
    Key: 
        Kind: Foo, id: 0, Parent: "P"
    Properties:
        description: "I am A."
Entity B:
    Key:
        Kind: Foo, id: 1, Parent: "P"
    Properties:
        description: "I am B"

TRANSACTION #1 BEGIN;
A.description = "I am new A";

TRANSACTION #2 BEGIN;
B.description = "I am new B";

TRANSACTION #1 COMMIT; -- *1
TRANSACTION #2 COMMIT; -- *2
```

Does *1 or *2 succeed?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> If there are two entities which belong to the same entity group, does an update of one entity on a transaction inhibits an update of the other entity on another transaction?

No and it's not about an `OR` is about an `AND`, so both transactions will be committed. As I understand from you schema, you try to use a transaction to update two separate documents, which will always work. It will also always work even if you whould have tried to update the same document, the order of commits being the order in which you call `commit()` on the transaction objects. So the result of your commits will be:

```
Entity A:
    Key: 
        Kind: Foo, id: 0, Parent: "P"
    Properties:
        description: "I am new A."
Entity B:
    Key:
        Kind: Foo, id: 1, Parent: "P"
    Properties:
        description: "I am new B"
```

Comment: Thanks alot! Do you have any reference to this behavior?

Comment: You're wlecome Yuki. Regarding references, you can check the offical documentation regarding [transactions](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/transactions) and regarding the order you can check Doug's answer from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49646498/firestore-order-of-writes).

Comment: Thanks again! The doc offers more information than that in gcp.